# Manually entered field code not working, but visually equivalent gui-entered one is working

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2011, field-codes

I am using Office 2011 (Norwegian version) for Mac, and I am trying to enter field codes. Every manually input field code so far is failing, whereas the ones I enter using `Insert->Field->...` is working.

- This does not work: Cmd+F9, entering PAGE into the brackets.
- This works: insert field -> PAGE

The result of both these is { PAGE } when viewing field codes (Opt+F9). Visually alike, yet only one is working. This is very inconsistent, and also makes working with conditional field codes impossible.

Image from running program in View Field Code mode:

[image]

Image from running program in Hide Field Code mode:

[image]

Example of stuff I cannot enter:

```
{ IF{ =MOD({PAGE}, 2) } = 0 "even" "odd"}
```

(Just an example - I know this is possible via the GUI).

How can I work around this? Is there some kind of "trick" to entering field codes in the mac version of office?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out [the answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/why-are-manually-entered-field-codes-not/723cbe20-f47f-4437-9aec-29cef96a980f?msgId=8297453a-2311-47f5-9828-1cf138afc452&rtAction=1434635828890) is as simple as pressing F9 after entering a field code.

**Why do I have to press F9?**

Because manually edited field codes are *not automatically updated*. That means a freshly inserted code will not show until you refresh its result.